# vector tile layer does not display when switching from VectorTile (3.10) to TileVector (3.11)

Tags: openlayers-3

I have this simple layer working with openlayers 3.10

```js
var roads = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.TileVector({
    format: new ol.format.TopoJSON(),
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 13}),
    tilePixelRatio: 16,
    url: 'http://MY_SERVER/{z}/{x}/{y}.topojson'
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 8,
      color: [0xff,0xff,0,0.3]
    })
  })
});
```

And then it is laid out on top of an OSM/mapnik layer:

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    mapnik,
    roads
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([25, 46]),
    zoom: 7,
    minZoom:7,
    maxZoom:17
  })
});
```

However the 3.11 version

```js
new ol.layer.VectorTile({
  source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
    // ...
  })
});
```

fails. The tile server is invoked, putting in a styling function reveals that the features are loaded properly, but no feature is displayed! There is no error on the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a tilePixelRatio of 16? That option was not available in 3.10, so I wonder why you have it in your snippet above. Also make sure that your vector tiles are in the same projection as your ol.View.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I edited my question to include the ol.View. Not sure the vector tiles are "in the same projection" as the ol.View?

Comment: Post the first couple of lines from one of your tiles, including some coordinates. Also I'm pretty sure you don't need the `tilePixelRatio: 16` setting.

Answer (score 1):

With `v3.11.0` release `ol.source.TileVector` was removed. You may use [`ol.source.VectorTile`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.source.VectorTile.html) from now on. Also change your code from `ol.layer.Vector` to [`ol.layer.VectorTile`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.layer.VectorTile.html). See [changelog](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases) and an [example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You can see in my question (the second code snippet) that I already know about ol.source.VectorTile and ol.layer.VectorTile. The example is nice but it uses Mapbox and I don't use Mapbox, as you can see in my code.